# How do I convert a series of if statements testing ranges into a switch?

Tags: c++

---

this my if condition code, but I can't convert it.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int num;
  cout << "please enter a number: ";
  cin >> num;

  if (num == 10)
  {
    cout << "Case 1";
  }
  else if (num > 19 && num < 21)
  {
    cout << "Case 2";
  }
  else if (num > 29 && num < 33)
  {
    cout << "Case 3";
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Invalid Number";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

what I tried to do was this:

```
    switch (num)
{
case 1:
 num==10;
  cout << "Case 1";
  break;
case 2: 
  num > 19 && num < 21;
  cout << "Case 2";
  break;
case 3:
  num> 29 && num < 33;
  cout << "Case 3";
  break;
default:
 cout << "Invalid Number";
}
```

it Ignores my condition and if I put my condition in place of "case 1" it gives me an error.

so , what can I do?

Comment: You can't use ranges in the `case` part of a `switch` statement.  The "arguments" to a `case` have to be constant integrals (numbers).  This allows the compiler to use the "argument" of a `case` as an index into an array of jump (branch) instructions.  This is an efficient implementation.

Comment: One alternative is to use the `if-else-if` ladder, like your first example.

Comment: For small ranges, you could make a `case` for each value in the range.  Not recommended for large ranges.  This method is based on the C++ property that `case` statements have *fall-through*.  Search the internet for "Duff's device".

Comment: Side note : `if (num > 19 && num < 21)` can be simplified to `if (num == 20)`

Comment: thank you so much for your information, it is really useful , I wasn't know that .@ThomasMatthews

Comment: @Cid, actually it is a task, or we can say homework I should do, maybe they wrote it like that to make me nervosa xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `switch` only selects individual values, but you can use case fall-through to let it combine multiple values. In your example, there aren't that many in the chosen ranges, so it might be appropriate:

```
switch (num)
{
case 10:
  cout << "Case 1";
  break;
case 20:
  cout << "Case 2";
  break;
case 30:
case 31:
case 32:
  cout << "Case 3";
  break;
default:
 cout << "Invalid Number";
}
```

Comment: I'm a paranoid bastard after having folk drop more `case`s after the `default` and now I `break;` the `default` as well.

Comment: Wow, that never crossed my mind. I've never seen someone do that, even to the point that I expected the compiler would warn about it. But nope! So that's a good recommendation I guess. The truly paranoid would enable `-Wimplicit-fallthrough` and then use [`[[fallthrough]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough) everywhere.

Comment: that is really an amazing answer, it never comes to my mind, I feel I am stupid when I can't fix my code.

Comment: Don't worry about that! I learned something today, too! :) I've been calling myself a programmer for 35 years now, and I can tell you the feeling of stupid never goes away. The best thing to do is get comfortable with it and enjoy the journey.

Comment: @paddy These days I'd definitely wall off the possibility with the compiler, but at the time the best I could do was add a new rule to the coding standard: "`default` comes last. Period." I wanted to add "`break;` `default` cases." but didn't have the political support.

Comment: And now that I think on the reasoning for the second rule being rejected, "Could screw up duff's device." could also apply to the first in weird enough cases.

Comment: thank you, I was afraid to ask a simple question like that, I thought people will get fool of me, but I found out many helped me without say something, and I even got more information. @paddy

Comment: @OmarMohamed A well-conceived question, even a simple one, is seldom a problem. Usually the worst that will happen is it'll be closed as a duplicate of an existing question. In that case, you still get an answer, the answer's just, "Over there." Where you'll run into problems is if it's been asked and answered many times AND easily searched for.